# Stop Canonical Ordering of Output List

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I'm working with the code below, which works well for my purposes; however, instead of the canonical ordering seen in the output, I want the output produced  in the order I give in the Cases line of code. Any help is most appreciated.

```
ClearAll;
m = {{N11, "x"}, {N12, "y"}, {N19, "z"}, {N20, "w"}, {N41, 
    "exz"}, {N42, "jy"}, {N49, "br"}, {N50, "mew"}, {N61, "qr"}, {N62,
     "xqe"}, {N539, "ycf"}, {N551, "pyu"}, {N559, "wq"}, {N560, 
    "hra"}};
Cases[m, {N19 | N560 | N41 | N61 | N551 | N20 | N539, __}];
TableForm[%]
```

Output from the above code

```
N19 z
N20 w
N41 exz
N61 qr
N539 ycf
N551 pyu
N560 hra
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alternatives = N19 | N560 | N41 | N61 | N551 | N20 | N539;
```

You can map `Cases` over the list of alternatives:

```
Join @@ Cases[{#, __}][m] & /@ (List @@ alternatives);

TableForm @ %
```

[image]

Alternatively, sort the output of `Cases` by the position in `alternatives` of the first column elements:

```
SortBy[PositionIndex[List @@ alternatives]@*First][Cases[m, {alternatives, __}]];

% // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks kglr; once again I very much appreciate you sharing your excellent skills! ... v/r ... prg

Comment: @PRG, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

The cases will be found in the order they occur in `m`.  If each case is unique, as in the example, the following can be used:

```
Sort[
 Cases[m, {N19 | N560 | N41 | N61 | N551 | N20 | N539, __}]
 ][[Ordering[N19 | N560 | N41 | N61 | N551 | N20 | N539]]]
```

Comment: Michael E2 ... thank u very much!!!

Comment: @PRG You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
m =
  {{N11, "x"}, {N12, "y"}, {N19, "z"}, {N20, "w"}, 
   {N41, "exz"}, {N42,"jy"}, {N49, "br"}, {N50, "mew"},
   {N61, "qr"}, {N62, "xqe"}, {N539, "ycf"}, {N551, "pyu"}, 
   {N559, "wq"}, {N560, "hra"}};

k = {N19, N560, N41, N61, N551, N20, N539};
```

Using `KeyTake` and `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
r = KeyTake[k] @ MapApply[Rule] @ m;
```

The result is an `Association`

```
Dataset[r]
```

[image]

Transform to `List`:

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ r
```

{{N19, "z"}, {N560, "hra"}, {N41, "exz"}, {N61, "qr"}, {N551,
"pyu"}, {N20, "w"}, {N539, "ycf"}}